# Stackless pre-order traversal in a binary tree

Tags: algorithm

Is it possible to perform **iterative** **pre-order** traversal on a binary tree without using node-stacks or  "visited" flags?

As far as I know, such approaches usually require the nodes in the tree to have pointers to their parents. Now, to be sure,   I know how to perform pre-order traversal using parent-pointers **and** visited-flags thus eliminating any requirement of stacks of nodes for iterative traversal.

But, I was wondering if visited-flags are really necessary. They would occupy a lot of memory if the tree has a lot of nodes. Also, having them would not make much sense if many pre-order tree traversals of a binary-tree are going on **simultaneously** in parallel.

If it is possible to perform this, some pseudo-code  or better a short C++ code sample would be really useful.

***EDIT:*** I specifically do *not* want to use **recursion** for pre-order traversal. The context for my question is that I have an octree (which is like a binary tree) which I have constructed on the GPU. I want to launch many threads, each of which does a tree-traversal independently and in parallel.

Firstly, CUDA does not support recursion. 
Seoncdly, the concept of visited flags applies only for a single traversal. Since many traversals are going on simultaneously , having visited-flags field in the node data structure is of no use. They would make sense only on the CPU where all independent tree traversals are/can be serialised. To be more specific,  after every tree-traversal we can set the visited-flags to false before performing another pre-order tree-traversal

Comment: Does recursion count as using stack?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Please see edit. I do not want to use recursion also.

Comment: why can't you use an external data structure for the visited flags (i.e. a Hashtable, add node once visited)?

Comment: Does the tree contain the information, for each node, which of its child nodes is "left" and which is "right"?

Comment: @max yes, each tree node does contain this information.

Comment: If you have visited flags, you don't also need parent pointers, one can just start from the root again. But you don't have them.. how about pre-order links? (ie each node has a pointer to the node the would come directly after it in a pre-order traversal)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this algorithm, which only needs parent pointers and no additional storage:

For an inner node, the next node in a pre-order traversal is its leftmost child.

For a leaf node: Keep going upwards in the tree until you are coming from the left child of a node with two children. That node's right child will then be the next node to traverse.

```py
function nextNode(node):
    # inner node: return leftmost child
    if node.left != null:
        return node.left
    if node.right != null:
        return node.right

    # leaf node
    while (node.parent != null)
        if node == node.parent.left and node.parent.right != null:
            return node.parent.right
        node = node.parent

    return null  #no more nodes
```

Comment: Using parent pointers amount to extra memory, no? Instead you can store the "next preorder node to visit". That would make the algorithm even simpler :p

Comment: Follow up: Think about it. A regular preorder traversal needs storing O(log(n)) pointers in the stack (one pointer at every level of the tree). Your algorithm needs O(n) extra pointers (one for every node). IMHO, this is not a "right" solution.

Comment: @Elkamina: True, but parent pointers have other uses as well. If you only need pre-order traversal then I agree that there are more memory-efficient methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can give each leaf node a pointer to the node that would come next in according to a preorder traversal.

For example, given the binary tree:

```
          A
         / \
        B   C
       / \
      D   E
           \
            F
```

D would need to store a pointer to E, and F would need to store a pointer to C.  Then you can simply traverse the tree iteratively as if it were a linked list.

You can do it with no extra storage by storing the same pointer in both the left and right subtree nodes.  Since such a structure is not allowed in a tree (that would make it a DAG), you can safely infer that any node where all "child" pointers point to the same place is a leaf node.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a single bit at each node signifying whether the first sub-branch addition went left-ward or rightward... Then, iterating through the tree allows choosing the original direction at every branch.

Comment: I think adding 1 bit per flag is precisely the kind of storage he wants to avoid.

Comment: I understood that the OP intended to avoid 'visited-flags' which is not what I meant here. These single- bit flags simply indicate the original insertion order. Furthermore a single bit is not that high a price, is it?

Comment: @smilingbuddha, you just raced me on this comment insertion :)

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on doing this, you could number every possible path through the tree, and then set each worker to follow that path.

Your numbering scheme can simply be that each zero-bit means take the left child, and each one-bit means take the right child. To execute a depth-first search, process your number from least-significant bit to most-significant.

While it is not necessary to know the depth of the tree in advance, if you don't you will need to handle the case where all further numbers hit a leaf before the number is fully consumed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a hack using the **absolute values** of the {->left,->right} pointers to encode *one bit per node*. It needs a first pass to get the initial pointer-"polarity" right.
It seems to be called DSW. 
You can find more in this https://groups.google.com/group/comp.programming/browse_thread/thread/3552ea0af2006b28/6323076923faec26?hl=nl&q=tree+transversal&lnk=nl& usenet thread.

I don't know if it can be expanded to quad-trees or oct-trees, and I seriously doubt if it can be extended to multithreaded access. Adding a parent pointer is probably easier...

Answer (score 0):

One direction you might want to consider is to delete the nodes of the tree as you traverse them and insert those nodes into a new tree. If you insert nodes in preorder, the new tree is going to be exactly same. But the problem here is how do you maintain integrity of the original tree as you delete items.